# Plotting from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, matplotlib

I want to improve my code. Is it possible to get the plot without repeating the same instructions multiple lines?

The data comes from a Pandas' dataframe, but I am only plotting the last column (Total Acc.)

[image]

[image]

```
e=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100

#The repetitions start:
row_awa = e.loc['AWA'] 
row_rem = e.loc['REM']
row_s1 = e.loc['S1'] 
row_s2 = e.loc['S2'] 
row_sws = e.loc['SWS'] 
row_stades = e.loc['stades'] 

#More repetitions
row_awa.plot()
row_rem.plot()
row_s1.plot()
row_s2.plot()
row_sws.plot()
row_stades.plot()


myLegend=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.2, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc=10, ncol=4,  #left, bottom, width, height
            title=r'TOTAL ACCURACY FOR MANY K-FOLD')                    #loc='center'
myLegend.get_title().set_fontsize('20')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce the repetitions you could make use of lists by doing something like:

```
labels = ['AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'stades']

rows = [] 
for label in labels:
    rows.append(e.loc[label]) 

# or even shorter with list comprehension 
rows = [e.loc[label] for label in labels]

for row in rows:
    row.plot()
```

Edit: The `labels` list can also be used as first argument of the `legend` function to show the correct labels.

Comment: Only Option 2 works. But that is fine. Also, how can I add the labels in the legend? So that instead of "Total Acc" I get the correct labels?

Comment: You could use a dictionary instead of a list and use the `iteritems` method of a dictionary but even more simple, probably you can use `labels` as the first argument of `plt.legend`.

Comment: You might want to add that part to the answer, comments are not permanent and this did answer a part of OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to slice your frame using the list of the zero level index of the data you're interested in. Drop the zero level index of that selection

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

level0indexes = ['AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'stades']
cols = ['Total Acc']
slicedf = df.loc[level0indexes, cols].reset_index(level = 0,drop=True).round(4)*100
x = list(range(len(slicedf)))
plt.xticks(x,  slicedf.index.tolist())
plt.plot(slicedf.values.flatten(),label=cols[0])
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

or even simpler, use pandas plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

level0indexes = ['AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'stades']
cols = ['Total Acc']
slicedf = df.loc[level0indexes, cols].reset_index(level = 0,drop=True).round(4)*100
plt.figure();
slicedf.plot();
plt.show();
```

The second method will allow you to choose to plot more than one column, just add the extra column names to the cols list

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use loc After unstacking.
no need for forloops.

In your code:

```
e=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100
e.unstack().loc[['AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'stades']].T.plot()
```

PS. Some code I made to reproduce the concept:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
# generate multiindex
idx = []
for letter in 'abcdefghij':
    for num in range(10):
        idx.append((letter,num))
# build dataframe        
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,10),
            index=pd.Index(idx))
# select 1 column, unstack, choose rows and plot.             
data[0].unstack().loc['a b d e g h'.split()].T.plot()
```